# How to allow a user to enter info into a database through wordpress

Tags: html, sql, database, wordpress

We have an algorithm, that in order to display an answer, needs user input into our database that the algorithm draws from to give the costumer our finds. We use wordpress as our site. Is there any program, plugin or way we can do this?

All answers are welcome,
Logan

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to achieve. I am not exactly sure what you are asking.   All I gather is you have an algorithm that returns a response based on user data. So why don't you make a web form to ask the user for the info then process it and return the result.

Comment: Sorry, the question is how would I process the user entry?

Comment: So you want to know how you can handle data in wordpress that comes from user entry. User entry implies a user is filling out data into a form. So you would handle it as you would handle any form in php.  Validate the post data and then handle the valid data and insert it into a relevant db table. I can show an example of this if you would like or you can look it up there are plenty of examples out there

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add/edit something in the database there is a plugin called Adminer which allows you to edit things in the database on which WordPress is installed.